# Source event strange latitude & longitude

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

My name is Cyrille and i'm working on a map app on codename one. The goal is to make an app that can search around the user for companies (with a search bar) and add companies they want to a list. Then the list appear in the main window and clicking on them show it on the map.

I've got a problem with the event part on codename one. Here's a part of my code :

```
PointLayer point = new PointLayer(new Coord(lat.doubleValue(), lng.doubleValue()),
                            companyName, null);
                    pl.addPoint(point);
                    pl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            PointLayer p = (PointLayer) evt.getSource();
                            System.out.println("pressed " + p);
                            Dialog.show("Details", "" + p.getName() + "\nLatitude: " + p.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: " + p.getLongitude(), "Ok", null);
                        }
                    });
```

Yes I took the basic map template ^^' 
My problem is : When i ask for the coordonates of point I get :

> {'longitude':2.3485853, 'latitude':48.8769309}

but when I ask for the coordonates of evt.getSource i get :

> {'longitude':261443.31964417442,'latitude':6254004.882818963}

which is kind of perturbing ...

I looked over the internet since yesterday but i didn't find any thing, maybe i'm not searching at the right place. Any clue of what's happening ?

EDIT : 
Thanks to the replyers i found the issue. The coordonates was given in an other system use by codename one : Popular Visualisation CRS Mercator. In order to use it you have to convert it with :  com.codename1.maps.Mercator.inverseMercator(latitude, longitude);
Or you can use google marker instead of codename one's [That's what i did]

Answer (score 2):

I think the coordinates you get in the event are in the Popular Visualisation CRS Mercator (EPSG:900913 or EPSG:3785) coordinate system, which is what the map control uses. The points you add in lat/lon are automatically transformed to this system when added to the map. "latitude" and "longitude" are slightly misleading; "x" and "y" are the standard terms for projected coordinates.

Comment: O_o thanks i did'nt know that. So is it possible to force the app to get non projected coord or do we have to convert them? ( I saw some articles with a lot of different formula depends on the version of projection)

Comment: You probably have to transform them back yourself. Try `com.codename1.maps.Mercator.inverseMercator(latitude, longitude);`. Since `Mercator` is the only implementation of `Projection`, I guess that's the one that's in use.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find why it returns this value but maybe you can bypass this issue by building a coord object. 
Example :

```
Coord coord = new Coord(lat.doubleValue(), lng.doubleValue());
PointLayer point = new PointLayer(coord, companyName, null);
                    pl.addPoint(point);
                    pl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            PointLayer p = (PointLayer) evt.getSource();
                            System.out.println("pressed " + p);
                            Dialog.show("Details", "" + p.getName() + "\nLatitude: " + coord.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: " + coord.getLongitude(), "Ok", null);
                        }
                    });
```

**EDITED**
I had the same problem 1 month ago. I resolved it by using the MapContainer and i use the addMarker(); from the map. By this way i can use it like this :

```
MapContainer map = new MapContainer(); // This used gMaps
for(Coord points : coords){
    map.addMarker((EncodedImage) myIcon, coord,"","", new ActionListener(){
       Dialog.show("Details", "" + p.getName() + "\nLatitude: " + points.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: " + points.getLongitude(), "Ok", null);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! Actually it work for a single point like my example. Unfortunatly I have the same problem with a map where there is a list of point on the map. The app should know what point is clicked so that it can take the coordonates. Since we cannot add an actionListener on pointLayer but only on pointLayers the coords object cannot bypass this issue ..

Comment: I'll try it and let you know !