# Adding x number Markers to Codenameone MapContainer at runtime

Tags: codenameone

I have retrieved a large number of latlong values and stored in an ArrayList. I want to add markers to my MapContainer using the latlong values in the ArrayList. The challenges however is  that the pins are never positioned correctly on the map (simulator and device). I have tried everything but still no success. Here is a working example. This works but the pins are positioned wrongly at runtime.

```
    Form hi = new Form("cReporter", new BorderLayout());
        hi.setScrollableY(false);
        Container n = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        MapContainer mc = new MapContainer();//
        mc.setShowMyLocation(true);
        hi.add("Center", mc);
        List lx = new ArrayList();
        addPoints(lx);
        hi.show();
        addMarkers(mc, lx);

       public void addPoints(List lx)
       {
           Map m= new HashMap();
           m.put("long", 8.993082);
           m.put("lat", 38.747393);
           lx.add(m);

           m= new HashMap();
           m.put("long", 8.988419);
           m.put("lat", 38.727094);
           lx.add(m);

           m= new HashMap();
           m.put("long", 8.991724);
           m.put("lat", 38.775203);
           lx.add(m);
       }

       public void addMarkers(MapContainer mc, List coordList)
   {    

        Style s = new Style();
        s.setFgColor(0xff0000);
        s.setBgTransparency(0);
        FontImage markerImg = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE, s, 5);

       for(Object m: coordList)
       {
           Map p= (Map)m;
           Coord moscone = new Coord(Double.parseDouble(p.get("lat").toString()), Double.parseDouble(p.get("long").toString()));
           mc.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false), mc.getCameraPosition(), "Hi marker", "Optional long description", new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("Bounding box is "+mc.getBoundingBox());
                    ToastBar.showMessage("You clicked the marker", FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
                }
            });
           mc.setCameraPosition(moscone);
           mc.revalidate();
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you aren't using the correct projection lat/long values for the map as these vary based on different implementations. See this for discussion of the different types of positioning: [Source event strange latitude & longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329529/source-event-strange-latitude-longitude/36331745)

I notice you create a new encoded image for every marker position. This is very inefficient as every such image would take up RAM and doing it x100 could introduce a serious overhead. This is an image you should reuse.

Comment: thanks Shai... I had mixed up the lat/long values.. and thanks for pointing out the EncodedImage issue